# Is the Tilde(~) supported by sharepoint 2016 to create SubSite?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

I tried to create subsite like "~Sub~Site~" in SP2016 but sometimes it takes too much time  creating  or sometimes throws error.

Does someone has official documentation of "Information about the characters that you cannot use in site names, folder names, and file names in SharePoint" for SP2016?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the (~) in the Site names, subsite names, or site group names as per the official MSFT article. this article is true for SharePoint 2016.

[Information about the characters that you cannot use in site names, folder names, and file names in SharePoint](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/905231/information-about-the-characters-that-you-cannot-use-in-site-names--fo)

But certian special characters allowed by MSFT in file names "&, ~, {, }"

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt346121%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#file